# How do I find a horse's lineage in Pocket Card Jockey?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds, pocket-card-jockey

I've played the same save of [Pocket Card Jockey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pocket_Card_Jockey) on my DS for years now, picking the game up any time I know I'll have some time to kill and putting it back down when I realize I have to do other things like eat and sleep.

Horses have different characteristics and skills, which can be passed to their offspring. However, inbreeding results in poor-temper horses. I think that you can balance those needs but have mostly been trying to avoid inbreeding as a matter of course.

My problem arises in forgetting what I was doing when I last took a breath to walk amongst the living. The in-game menu is not the most intuitive and the game's fandom is on the small side, meaning documentation is thin.

I have avoided, so far, creating any sort of spreadsheet to track this because sometimes I am aware of what restraint looks like. Is there an in-game way to see a horse's ancestors so I can avoid inbreeding without meticulous out-of-game notes?